# Change working directory in command prompt based on user input

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I have a batch file like the below:

```
@echo off
cd\
title Build Batch
cd C:\ProgramData\CodeBase\ 
dir
set /p codeBase=Enter the CodeBase: %=%
@echo Build for %codeBase%
cd\
cd C:\ProgramData\CodeBase\%codeBase%\my_code_folder\build
pause
```

If I execute it, it runs fine till it gets the user input and print the value of the variable **codeBase**. After that it fails to change the working directory and just stands still.

How to make it to change the working directory based on the user input?

Comment: if codeBase has spaces in it, then use `cd "C:\ProgramData\CodeBase\%codeBase%\my_code_folder\build"` (note the double-quotes)

Comment: Yep, quote everything that you can, especially directory names and user-entered values.

Answer (score 0):

A possible working code for your task could be:

```
@echo off
title Build Batch
cd /D C:\ProgramData\CodeBase\ 
rem List only names of subdirectories sorted by name.
dir /AD /B /ON
set /p "codeBase=Enter the CodeBase: "
echo Build for %codeBase%
cd "C:\ProgramData\CodeBase\%codeBase%\my_code_folder\build"
pause
```

The double quotes may be the important difference to your code.